# Trying to recreate the Google landing page using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to recreate the nav bar at the top of the google landing page using flexbox, but I'm pretty confused as to how it works. I can't seem to get some of the content to the right of my nav bar, and the other content to the left. My #items are my ul of content for the nav bar, and .left and .right are the respective content that I want to move around, currently, everything is just squished together on the left. 
Here is my HTML:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Google Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- CODE HERE-->
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul id="items">
        <li class="left">About</li>
        <li class="left">Store</li>
        <li class="right">Gmail</li>
        <li class="right">Images</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#items {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  justify-self: flex-start;
}

.right {
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: There's no `justify-self` in flexbox. Those rules are just being ignored. Use `justify-content` or auto margins. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276

Comment: In addition to what @Micheal Benjamin said, ```align-self``` is used to align a single element vertically.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is instead of putting all of your `items` in one list put them in two separate lists and then style them individually like this:
HTML:

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
        <button class="sign-in">Sign In</button>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

nav a,
i {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.75;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.sign-in {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #4285f4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4387fd, #4683ea);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```